# How do I copy Unique constraint in Oracle with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, oracle, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a table (on which I have no control) that I must copy. The target schema can be the same as the original one, so all indexes and constraints have to be defined without a name, implicitly.

I'm using Python 3.4.3 with SQLAlchemy 1.0.8 and cx_oracle 5.2.

The table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE" 
(   "ITEMID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LABEL" NVARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FIRSTCHILDID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LASTCHILDID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DEFAULTPARENTID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PICTUREID" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SECURITYID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("ITEMID")
    UNIQUE ("LABEL"));
```

The code I'm using is at https://gist.github.com/toyg/9fb541ff3dbc8c175329 but the core of it is this (smeta and dmeta are source and target Metadata, bound):

```
table = Table(table_name, smeta, autoload=True)
target_name = prefix + str(table.name)
target_table = table.tometadata(dmeta, name=target_name)
for constraint in target_table.constraints:
    constraint.name = None
target_table.metadata.create_all(dengine)
```

It fails with this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) 
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object 
[SQL: b'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sys_c009016 ON "TMP_MY_TABLE" (label)']
```

This is because SQLAlchemy is trying to create the Unique index after creating the table, when it's already too late: CREATE INDEX requires a name, so SA uses the same name as the existing one, and it fails.

I tried setting the index name to None before creation, to give SA a hint, but that results in errors because it expects a string there at all times.

Is there any way to tell SA to just append the bloody UNIQUE clause to the table DDL right away?

Comment: You are trying to clone data? If schema is the same

Comment: Yes, I have to copy the entire table. Schema may or may not be the same; the problem obviously comes up when it is, but tbh, name collisions could happen even in different schemas.

Comment: did you try something like `constraint.name = prefix + constraint.name`? In this case you'll have names for constraints, and they will differ from existing constraints.

Comment: sorry, I meant setting index name

Comment: Thanks @pavel_form , I hadn't thought about that. It's still a bit of a workaround, but if I can't find any better way I'll go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"UNIQUE INDEX" means that the `Index` construct is used.  Its DDL is not emitted within the CREATE TABLE.  It sounds like you are looking for a `UniqueConstraint` construct.   It seems likely that in this case, Oracle returns reflected information about what you first created as a `UniqueConstraint` object as an `Index` object with unique=True (these constructs are "different", but on many backends they are synonymous and/or mixed and matched and sometimes even mirrored, it's totally confusing).

at the end of the day if you want the UNIQUE keyword as an inline constraint you need to use the `UniqueConstraint` object, and you'd need to remove this `Index` from the table - you might be able to get away with `table.indexes.remove(index)`.   The `Index` object wouldn't be in `table.constraints`.    You probably want to do your "copy" of the table in a more programmatic way rather than using tometadata().    Look perhaps into using the [inspection interface](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/reflection.html#fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector) directly and just build the `Table` you want from that.